# Using GLM to identify differences in abundance of individuals between years and sites

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multiple-regression, autocorrelation

I have 5 samples of Ephemoptera abundance taken at four streams across a number of years (2012-2017), during the time series a flood occurred (2014).

Samples at each stream were taken at the same sampling location in all years.
Each stream has a different level of habitat complexity. Therefore the impact of a flood is expected to vary between streams.

[image]

I want to identify if abundance varies between streams and years.
I am interested to know if abundance varies between years at a given site in the study but also I am interested to know if abundance varies between sites in a given year. 
I believe this question is suitable for analysis using a GLM approach.
I am working in r.
The code for my initial glm is below.

```
ephlm <- glm(Ephemoptera ~ Year, data=reg, family=gaussian)
ephlm2 <- glm(Ephemoptera ~ Year + Stream, data=reg, family=gaussian)
```

Using maximum liklihood estimation a normal distribution is found to fit the model residuals best.

I believe there is potential for temporal autocorrelation at a given site. Running the autocorrelation function of the residuals of a model only containing year and a model containing year and site appears to support this.

```
acf(residuals(ephlm))
acf(residuals(ephlm2))
```

[image]
[image]

I have two main questions:

1 - Is my study design suitable for glm (or do I need to consider applying a repeated measures approach)?

2 - Is there a way to add in a temporal autocorrelation factor into glm?

Comment: Can you explain what Months and Replicate stand for? In particular, why do you have Months = 13 and large variation in the values of Replicate? Abundance seems to be a count variable (warranting a Poisson family), though it's not clear how the Replicate factors into the Abundance. If a flood occurred in 2014, shouldn't your model include a dummy variable for when the flood occurred?

Comment: Hi Isabella, Months are the number of months since the first samples were taken (August 2013) I may need to incorporate months as I have a post flood sample taken in 2014 which was taken in October (as opposed to August in all other years) and therefore may have differences in abundance based upon differences in season. Replicate is a dummy variable which I was planning to use as a random effect because I believe I have temporally repeated measures (the same riffle at each site is sampled for ephemoptera abundance in each year).